# How to delete an item from my Reducer Object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an object in my reducer like this :

```js
clientData : {
1080 : [{ID : 1111,name : 'John'},{ID : 2222,name : 'Stan'},],
1090 : [{ID : 3333,name : 'Adam'},{ID : 4444,name : 'Alan'},]
}
```

And I want to be able to delete an item (for example Stan with 2222 ID's)
The problem that is I don't have the key of my property (1080), and I don't have any idea how to achieve it.
I've tried the **Object.values(object1)**  but it convert my object to array and I lost all my architecture.
Have you an idea please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing from existing objects might not be good, you can use Object.entries and filter to remove id.

If you want to change existing pass `data` to `reducer`

```js
const data = {
  1080: [
    { ID: 1111, name: "John" },
    { ID: 2222, name: "Stan" },
  ],
  1090: [
    { ID: 3333, name: "Adam" },
    { ID: 4444, name: "Alan" },
  ],
};

const remove = (id, data) => {
  const entries = Object.entries(data);
  return entries.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    const newValue = value.filter((item) => item.ID !== id);
    acc[key] = newValue;
    return acc;
    // return { ...acc, [key]: newValue };
  }, {}); // for updating existing data here
};


console.log(remove(2222, data))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but what if I want to update the item instead of delete it ?